# Celery client define custom Producer (auto_declare)

Tags: python, celery, amqp, kombu

Having trouble turning off `auto_declare` in Kombu Producer ([docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/projects/kombu/en/stable/userguide/producers.html#reference)). As I understood correctly at Celery init you can pass kombu Producer in `amqp=...` ([docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery-application-objects)) but I was not very successful with it. Having function which is using default kombu Producer as seen in documentation.

```
def celery_app(
        service_name: str
) -> Celery:

    return Celery(
        __name__,
        result_backend=settings.CELERY_RESULT_URL,
        broker="%s/%s" % (settings.BASE_CELERY_BROKER_URL, service_name),
        task_create_missing_queues=False,
        celery_queue_ha_policy="all",
        task_acks_late=True,
        set_as_current=False,
        result_extended=True,
    )
```

I'd expect to just pass `amqp=AMPQ(Producer(...))` like? :

```
    return Celery(
        __name__,
        result_backend=settings.CELERY_RESULT_URL,
        broker="%s/%s" % (settings.BASE_CELERY_BROKER_URL, service_name),
        task_create_missing_queues=False,
        celery_queue_ha_policy="all",
        task_acks_late=True,
        set_as_current=False,
        result_extended=True,
        amqp=AMQP(Producer(
            channel="%s/%s" % (settings.BASE_CELERY_BROKER_URL,
                               service_name), # (amqp://...)?
            exchange=...
            auto_declare=False
        ))

    )
```

but sadly that is not how it works. Can anyone help?

Thanks!